# How to parse an XML coming from Kafka topic via Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to Parse XML coming from Kafka topic using Spark Streaming.
com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 is able to parse XML but only from files in HDFS.

Already tried with library : `com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1` ;

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "ServiceRequest").load("/tmp/sanal/gems/gem_opr.xml") ;
```

Actual Results :
1) Take the stream in Spark
2) Parse the XML Stream in the poutput

Answer (score 2):

You can use `com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader.xmlRdd(spark: SparkSession, xmlRDD: RDD[String]): DataFrame` method to read xml from `RDD<String>`. For example:

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml

// setting up sample data
List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();
recordsList.add(new ConsumerRecord<String, String>("topic", 1, 0, "key",
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><catalog><book id=\"bk101\"><genre>Computer</genre></book></catalog>"));

JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd = spark.parallelize(recordsList);

// map ConsumerRecord rdd to String rdd
JavaRDD<String> xmlRdd = rdd.map(r -> {
    return r.value();
});

// read xml rdd
new XmlReader().xmlRdd(spark, xmlRdd)
```